# Hebrew send to google spreadsheet from PowerShell Hebrew correctly

Tags: powershell, google-sheets, encoding, hebrew

[image]Please help.
In console look hebrew correct but in spreadsheet is not correct[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtcqz.png)

```
    $import = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)  
$import.Add( @("route_id"))
$import.Add( @( 'אבא אבן 1 הרצליה' ))  | Out-NULL
               
 
try {
    
   $Response = Set-GSheetData -accessToken $accessToken -rangeA1 "A1:X$($import.Count)" -sheetName "23-07-21" -spreadSheetID $SpreadsheetID -values $import -Verbose 
   $Response | ConvertTo-Json
   
} catch {
    $err = $_.Exception
    $err | Select-Object -Property *
    "Response: "
    $err.Response
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hebrew might not be supported in Sheets, you would need to [install a font](https://www.alphr.com/how-to-change-the-font-in-google-sheets/). You can try with this one

https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Hebrew?query=hebrew

### Update

After testing using the Rest API, it works, so the issue might be related on how the PowerShell process hebrew characters.

I've found some information on how to process hebrew characters in the Windows Powershell

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1255)
```

Make sure the console is outputting the right characters and the `POST` a request to Google Sheets

Comment: I can entry from keyboard on hebrew

Comment: I've never done it programatically though, what happens if you add the characters via rest API on https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

Comment: @IvanGavrilov I tested it using the Rest API 

`POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID]/values/A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "values": [
    [
      "אבא אבן 1 הרצליה"
    ]
  ]
}`

Comment: My POST request worked, What do you see in the formula bar if you select the cell that has the question marks?

Comment: On console output correct

Comment: Did you try to send the string using the Windows encoding to the API?

Answer (score 0):

It's bug in the psmodule. Author must specify encoding UTF8.
https://github.com/umn-microsoft-automation/UMN-Google/pull/50